# Restore css property of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, session-storage

I am trying to restore a display property (`none` or `block`) from a div, after my site refreshes. I have multiple div's with that class, but the have a unique ID. Inside those div's are some checkboxes that refreshes the site after they get checked/unchecked.

Here is a **jsfiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/074jatfs/2/

This is my sidebar with my div's and checkboxes:

```
<div class="filter-panel filter--property facet--property" data-filter-type="value-list" data-field-name="f">
   <div class="filter-panel--flyout" style="border:none;"><div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title"><h3>Filter Group 1</h3></label></div>
   <div class="filter-panel--content" id="FilterGroup1">
      <ul class="filter-panel--option-list" style="list-style-type:none;">
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="603"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <label>Filter 1</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="613"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
         </span>
             <label>Filter 2</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="filter-panel filter--property facet--property" data-filter-type="value-list" data-field-name="f">
   <div class="filter-panel--flyout" style="border:none;"><div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title"><h3>Filter Group 2</h3></label></div>
   <div class="filter-panel--content" id="FilterGroup2">
      <ul class="filter-panel--option-list" style="list-style-type:none;">
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="603"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <label>Filter 3</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="613"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
         </span>
             <label>Filter 4</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
         <div class="filter-panel filter--property facet--property" data-filter-type="value-list" data-field-name="f">
   <div class="filter-panel--flyout" style="border:none;"><div id="label-it" class="label-it"><label class="filter-panel--title"><h3>Filter Group 3</h3></label></div>
   <div class="filter-panel--content" id="FilterGroup3">
      <ul class="filter-panel--option-list" style="list-style-type:none;">
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="603"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
            </span>
            <label>Filter 5</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         <li class="filter-panel--option">
            <div class="option--container" style="display:block;">
            <span class="filter-panel--checkbox"><input type="checkbox" value="613"><span class="checkbox--state">&nbsp;</span>
         </span>
             <label>Filter 6</label>
         </div>
         </li>
         </ul>
         </div>
         </div>
```

When the div `label-it` is clicked the div `filter-panel--content` toggles from `display:block` to `display:none` and the other way (`display:none` to `display:block`)

At this point I want to save the current property of `display` and restore it when the site refreshes.

This is my first try to **sessionStorage** the property, I tried to set it in the toggle function:

```
$('.label-it').click(function() {

  $(this).closest(".filter-panel--flyout").find(".filter-panel--content div").toggle(350)

sessionStorage.setItem("filterstate", $("#FilterGroup1").css("display"));

});
```

To restore the `filterstate` I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    sessionStorage.getItem("filterstate");
    if (sessionStorage.getItem("filterstate"))
    {
        $("#FilterGroup1").css("display", sessionStorage.getItem("filterstate"));
    }
});
```

I cant restore the css property, can someone help me? Please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to instead try storing the `display` value for the div which is actually toggled
and not its parent.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("filterstate", $("#FilterGroup1 .option--container").css("display"));
```

Comment: Problem solved, used the getItem-Function at a wrong place! (Y) Thanks!